# Logitech c270 webcam and Skype

Tags: 12.04, pulseaudio, skype, microphone, logitech

I have recently purchased the Logitech c270 webcam to use for Skype. The video works perfectly, but the mic is useless.

I have changed the input to the mic on system settings and pulseaudio, and it gives feedback and shows that the mic is working. I have also successfully recorded a clip with it on Audacity and that works fine.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have a C270 web cam I had the same problem. When I installed **Wine** and launched the **Wine Configuration** → **Audio tab** → **Voice Input Device** → (in the drop down arrow showed USB device), selected it and applied. Tested using Skype and test never missed a beat since.