# Logitech Webcam C270 sound to start slow

Tags: 14.04, pulseaudio, skype, webcam, logitech

I have a Logitech C270 webcam on Ubuntu 14.04 for use with Skype (4.3.0.37). The webcam video works flawlessly, but sound always needs about 5 minutes and/or a couple of other things to work.

What I found is that sounds works once:

- I've been into Skype options->video devices - this turns the green light on the webcam on
- I've gone into sound devices, opened PulseAudio settings and changed either volume on the webcam or clicked anything else
- there is still some sort of lag of at least 2 minutes of waiting.

I can not use this answer: [Logitech c270 webcam and Skype](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181367/logitech-c270-webcam-and-skype) as the webcam does not appear in Audio devices, only pulseaudio does.

Here is output of lspci:

```
    00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
    00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
    00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
    00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
    00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05)
    00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
    00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
    00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev d5)
    00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev d5)
    00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05)
    00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H87 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
    00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
    00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
    01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Oland [Radeon HD 8570 / R7 240 OEM]
    01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7700/7800 Series]
    03:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
    03:00.1 Bluetooth: Ralink corp. RT3290 Bluetooth
    04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
```

I'm not sure if I'm running skype in wine. See output from ps -ef:

```
ps -ef |grep skype
jochen    2935  2580  2 Jan22 ?        02:23:28 skype
jochen   14941 29456  0 15:26 pts/11   00:00:00 grep skype

ps -ef |grep wine
jochen    8443  2580  0 Jan23 ?        00:02:28 wineserver
jochen   14892 29456  0 15:25 pts/11   00:00:00 grep wine
```

I cannot even see the webcam in here?

Any ideas how I can diagnose this further?

Comment: Are you running Skype under wine???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I suggest you to use [Skype for Linux](http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/) instead of Wine.

Wine is an emulator. Because of that, high latency for audio that capturing from your webcam is an expected thing.

Secondly, make sure that your mic volume not more than %100.

[image]

Thirdly, make sure that in [Alsamixer](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/Alsamixer) CAPTURE feed both left and right zero.

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I had Skype for Linux installed, but removal and fresh installation solved the problem.